# Create a responsive and cross-platform C# application by using ASP.NET and a locally-deployed Web server?

Tags: c#, asp.net, mono, cross-platform, xsp

I need to create a cross-platform app and I'm considering our alternatives. The app is very complex, it will need to show video, graphs and charts and allow user interaction with them.

I think 75% of my users will use desktops to access the app, and 25% will use tablets or smart-phones.

Another constraint is that I highly prefer to develop in C#, as most of my company's code is written in this language.

The cross-platform requirement is obviously tough to satisfy. I am considering creating a web-based app in ASP.NET. This is nice as it will allow running on iPad, Android, Win, etc. with minimal porting effort, however the slowness of interaction with a remote server has me worried.

Then I had this idea: How about creating an ASP.NET app; but for desktop users, I'll deploy a **local server** on their machine, with direct access to local video files, etc. Thus, they'd get much better responsiveness. For mobile users, I'll have them use the remote server. Since ASP.NET server is too expensive to be installed with every client, I can serve their pages from Mono's free ASP.NET server (XSP).

Will this work? Any thoughts will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you considered using Mono?

Comment: It can work.  I wouldn't recommend it.  It's not usually a good idea to requre desktop users to install IIS on their machines.  Opens up too many cans of worms...  Howevfer, we did this for one very unique situation where it was deemed worth the effort for an internal app.  Not knowing all your requirements and all other factors being equal, I'd stick with standard ASP.NET and host it on your own server.  There are just so many less hassles to deal with.  Deployment/update hassles will likely outweigh any "benefits".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not so good idea. Users will not be pleased when you install webserver on their desktops. And deployment of this webserver will be more difficult compare to common desktop app. If i were you, i would create web app as universal app for all platforms, after that you can create special app for desktops on mono or .net if it will be useful.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It looks like we'll do a Windows .NET app with a webservice back end, and supplement it with a more limited Web app further down the road.